# how to let drupal's editor recognize programming language and highlight its syntax?

Tags: drupal, editor, syntax-highlighting

I am using drupal serving as a blog system. Now I need to show sample code in the articles. How can I let the editor recognize the programming language and highlight the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the WYSIWYG editor you're using, you should have the option to add `<pre>` tags, which will preserve spacing so your code is formatted properly.

You can then style the `<pre>` tags in your CSS, or use something like [this Google code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html), which will do syntax highlighting.

You may have to allow the `<pre>` tag in your tag whitelist in your Drupal admin, under Admin > Configuration > Text Formats (for Drupal 7) or Admin > Site Configuration > Input Formats (for Drupal 6).